# Как правильно сохранять БД при пересборке докера?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть собранный образ докера. Его скопировали пользователю. Пользователь им пользуется.

Появились изменения и пользователю высылается новый собранный образ. Чтобы пользователю не потерять данные своей БД ему надо будет сделать экспорт/импорт БД или достаточно будет скопировать/вставить содержимое каталога БД?

Как правильно это делается?

Comment: Мы в своей системе храним базы вне докера. У нас posgres, соответственноь монтируем `/var/lib/postgresql/` на файловую систему хоста. При замене образа с базами ничего не происходит, так как они расположены вне контейнера. Разумеется, предполагается, что новая версия СУБД бинарно совместима с базами. Если же в образе поменялся движок СУБД, то нужно экспортировать-импортировать.

Comment: Возможно глупый вопрос, а где сам сбилденный контейнер лежит(который хочу переслать)? я зашел в **/var/lib** и папку **docker** не дает открыть

Comment: Зачем пересылать контейнер? Нужно пересылать образ и `docker-compose.yaml` который содержит параметры для запуска. Например, для постгреса можно прописать порт, пользователя, пароль и т.п. Бинарный формат образа создаётся командой `docker save`, распаковывается на получателе командой `docker load`. Если нужно именно контейнер отправить, то команды `docker export`/`docker import`

Comment: т.е. получается если докер содержит 3 котейнера (3 сервиса, описанных в *.yml), то чтобы не собирать на стороннем ПК (напримиер, там нет Интернета) то достаточно будет сделать **docker export** для каждого на собираемой машине и **docker import** на машине где нет Интернета?

Comment: Да, каждый контейнер нужно экспортировать/импортировать индивидуально.